# Difference between Msxml2.DOMDocument and Msxml2.XMLHTTP

Tags: domdocument, xmlhttprequest

What is the difference between:

```
Msxml2.DOMDocument
Msxml2.XMLHTTP
```

? And of course, the other question is which one will work best for my purpose as described below?

The context is this - I have code that makes many calls to retrieve web pages. I am looking for the most efficient object for this task. For example, something like this:

```
Dim oXmlHttp : Set oXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

oXmlHttp.Open "GET", sUri, False
oXmlHttp.Send
If Err Then
    getWebPage = "ERROR - could not get the source text of the webpage."
    Exit Function
End If
sResponse = oXmlHttp.responseBody
```

This seems to work the same way if I create an object using:

```
Dim oXmlHttp : Set oXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

Can anyone explain or point me to a reference that clearly outlines the differences (and intended usages) for each of those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to learn more about MSXML, these links may help:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766487(v=vs.85).aspx

In short, `XMLHTTP` is used to retrieve information, while `DOMDocument` is used to structure and parse it.

This page explains it better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760218(v=vs.85).aspx

`DOMDocument` "Represents the top node of the XML DOM tree." while `XMLHTTP` "Provides client-side protocol support for communication with HTTP servers."

Comment: makes perfect sense, thanks for the point in the right direction.